# Force Facebook to not display any notification about friends' activity

Tags: facebook

Since past 3-4 weeks or so Facebook started adding notifications related to my friends activity to my notification area. Where previously I was notified only about activity around my posts, I can now see:

> X added a new photo. Y commented on... Z posted a video and A wrote for the first time in a while.

I'm terrified with this new feature. I have quite a lot friends, but I'm visiting Facebook once per 2-3 weeks and post once per 1-2 month. Thus, before introduction of this feature, with every visit I could find around 3-5 notifications about my own posts, activity or responses.

Now, with each visit I can se around 30-60 notifications about added photos, comments etc.

It seems that I have turned off everything that I could turn off:

[image]

and I'm still bloated with these notifications. **How can I turn them off**?

[This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/29011/21486) brought no help to me. It deals with change in Facebook that took place four years ago, while I'm talking about really recent change.

Comment: Could you please update your screenshot to show that you have `Close Friends activity (Choose whether you want to get notifications about Close Friends)` set to `Off`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was probably very sleepy when I wrote this, because I can see it in your screenshot. My comments can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the magic behind disabling this kind of notification is unfollowing your friends.

Here is the magic button to be pressed for each and everyone of such persons:

[image]

I'm not using "Home" section of Facebook at all so I don't know, if unfollowing someone means that you'll see no notifications from that person at all, both in "Home" and in notification slider.

I'm pretty sure that yes. I think, that starting from some time, there is no distinction in Facebook between these two places and your decision is only -- either to see all notifications, in both places, or to mute them all, permanently.